# High-performance decorator pattern for structured objects

Tags: c++, performance, oop, design-patterns, decorator

Imagine I have a large data structure, let's say a huge `vector`, whose creation is not under my control (i.e. I cannot modify its static type), containing objects of class `InitialFunctionality`. In C++:

```
class InitialFunctionality
{
 public:
 void iCanDoThis();
}

hugeVector vector<InitialFunctionality>; // <- lots of elements inside! :)
```

My goal is to **dynamically** extend the functionality of the `InitialFunctionality` objects in `hugeVector` with the lowest performance impact possible to, let's say:

```
class ExtraFunctionality: public InitialFunctionality
{
 public:
 int iOfferThisToo;
}
```

The well-known [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) works great for unstructured objects. You can use it to dynamically extend the functionality of objects from the `InitialFunctionality` class and happily pass them around ever after.

But how to extend the objects in `hugeVector` without changing its ordering and with the smallest performance impact? For instance, duplicating the vector is a no-go due to it's size.

I was thinking about using some sort of [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for the vector, which keeps a reference to the original `hugeVector` and lazily transforms the contained objects on demand (i.e. as the adapted vector elements are accessed). However, apart from the transformation itself, (i.e. initializing `iOfferThisToo`), which is required by any method, this requires keeping a cache to check whether an object was already transformed or not. Such cache can be really expensive.

Comment: Is `InitialFunctionality` under your control?

Comment: @AndyProwl assuming you mean the definition of `InitialFunctionality`: no, it's not under my control. Otherwise I would be able to add my extra functionality there. That could be considered ugly in terms of design but it would be good in terms of performance which is what I am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

If you weren't adding extra members, you should be able to do something like:

```
class myInternalFunctionality : public InternalFunctionality {
public:
    //new features
    void ICanDoThis();

private:
    // disable all ctors
};
```

and then recast pointers to the InternalFunctionality in the vector.

```
myInternalFunctionality* myInternalPtr = &hugeVector[i];
myInternalPtr->ICanDoThis();
```

Since you are, I think you've got some trouble.

Comment: Can you elaborate? For starters I don't see how `InternalFunctionality` adds my extra data member `iOfferThisToo`. Assuming no extra transformation is implied, your solution simply incorrect (and dangerous!) because there was no allocation for the extra members present in `myInternalFunctionality` and not present in `InternalFunctionality`

Comment: I didn't say it was a good idea, and you didn't say there were extra members.  Storage for a class is basically the same as a structure, so this works if you want to simply add methods.

Comment: I did say there were extra members, `iOfferThisToo` **is** a member in my question. Please read carefully. Plus, your statement about storage is also not true when adding virtual methods.